# How do I create an input field that only the users can see and not the admin?

Tags: python, django, forms, privacy, cloud9

Currently I'm creating a website using Django. The purpose of my website involves storing personal information to the user. For user privacy and security sakes. I'm trying to make it so that I (The Admin) can't see what they have put in the Text or CharFields that gets displayed on their own personal homepage in order to make the user feel more comfortable putting their info on site. I have tried encrypting it just like a password kind of like so:

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

but it wouldn't let me or the user add anything to the form. Plus the old fields were shown as encrypted to the user. The way I want it is so that it looks encrypted to me on my admin page but to the user's page it should be normal text. So my one question is how would I be able to accomplish this feat? Or is it even possible?

Comment: If you're asking about passwords specifically, it's a huge security concern if you can show a user their password. If you use a proper password management system like the one django provides, there is no way for you to know what password the user has.

Comment: How about hiding the field altogether in the admin pages? The field itself won't be "encrypted" in any manner, meaning you'll still be able to see it using database queries, but it won't pop up on the default admin pages.

Comment: @user2896976 thanks for your feedback, it's not only about passwords however, it's about all the input fields. The way my website works is that basically kind of like a contact list. I wasnt user to feel safe putting in their friends names and phone numbers without being worried that I (the admin) will see what they put and call them. I've tried using the password widget but it came out encrypted on their page too.

Comment: @Shovalt thanks for your suggestion, but how would I do that?

Comment: @X-TremeFighter12 see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that as long as some informations are stored in your system - either unencrypted or with a reversible encryption -, someone (sysadmin, dbadmin, devs, etc)  _will_ have to access it at some stage, even if only for purely technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply excluding the private fields from the admin pages. This is described in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude), and requires creating a file named `admin.py` in your module (same directory where `models.py` is). In that file you need to create a class with the same name as your model, but with the suffix 'Admin', and under that class have an `exclude` option with the names of the fields you would like to hide. See the docs for the exact implementation.

As mentioned in the comments, this is **not a good practice** for storing actual passwords. I assumed from the context of the question that this is less sensitive, yet private, data.